# Parameters not transfering through screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to pass some parameters through different screens. I had successfully done it before in different parts of the application, but for some reason, it is not working all of a sudden, and I am not sure why?

navigator:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import FilterScreen from '../screens/HomeScreens/FilterScreen';
import SortScreen from '../screens/HomeScreens/SortScreen';

import { SearchFilterSortContextProvider } from '../context/SearchFilterSortContext';

const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStackNav = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='HomeScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="FilterHomeScreen" component={FilterScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="SortHomeScreen" component={SortScreen}/>
    </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

export default HomeStackNav
```

HomeScreen:

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

import SearchAndFilterComponent from '../components/HomeScreen/SearchAndFilterComponent';
import ResultsComponent from '../components/HomeScreen/ResultsComponent';

import { SearchFilterSortContextProvider } from '../context/SearchFilterSortContext';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation, route}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log(route.params)
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [navigation])
  
  return (
    <SearchFilterSortContextProvider>
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <SearchAndFilterComponent/>
        <View style={styles.fullSplit}></View>
        <ResultsComponent />
      </View>
    </SearchFilterSortContextProvider>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fullSplit: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }
})

export default HomeScreen
```

Sort Screen Component making the call:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

import { SearchFilterSortContext } from '../../context/SearchFilterSortContext'

const SortOptionsComponent = () => {
  const {sort, setSort} = useContext(SearchFilterSortContext)
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  return (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort:'Homes_for_You'})}} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Homes For You</Text>
          {
            sort === 'Homes_for_You' ? <Feather name='check' color={'black'} size={20}/> : null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort:'Newest'})}} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Newest</Text>
          {
            sort === 'Newest' ? <Feather name='check' color={'black'} size={20}/> : null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort:'Price_High_Low'})}} style={styles.row}>
          <View style={styles.rowIcon}>
            <Text style={[styles.text, styles.price]}>Price</Text>
            <Feather name='arrow-down' size={22} color={'black'}/>
          </View>
          {
            sort === 'Price_High_Low' ? <Feather name='check' color={'black'} size={20}/> : null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort:'Price_Low_High'})}} style={styles.row}>
          <View style={styles.rowIcon}>
            <Text style={[styles.text, styles.price]}>Price</Text>
            <Feather name='arrow-down' size={22} color={'black'}/>
          </View>
          {
            sort === 'Price_Low_High' ? <Feather name='check' color={'black'} size={20}/> : null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort:'Bedrooms'})}} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Bedrooms</Text>
          {
            sort === 'Bedrooms' ? <Feather name='check' color={'black'} size={20}/> : null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort:'Bathrooms'})}} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Bathrooms</Text>
          {
            sort === 'Bathrooms' ? <Feather name='check' color={'black'} size={20}/> : null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort:'Square_Feet'})}} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Sqft.</Text>
          {
            sort === 'Square_Feet' ? <Feather name='check' color={'black'} size={20}/> : null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort:'Lot_Size'})}} style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Lot Size</Text>
          {
            sort === 'Lot_Size' ? <Feather name='check' color={'black'} size={20}/> : null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  nav: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '500'
  },
  row: {
    paddingVertical: 12,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'lightgrey',
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  rowIcon: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  price: {
    marginRight: 4
  }
})

export default SortOptionsComponent
```

When it runs `navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {sort: 'Homes_for_You'})`, it does go back to the home screen but prints this:

```
{"key": "HomeScreen-woUXGRPlOtjfIhEY51Ew1", "name": "HomeScreen", "params": undefined}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function in `HomeScreen` and `SortScreen` be like:

`HomeScreen`:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (route.params) {
    console.log(route.params)
  }
}, [route.params]);
```

`SortScreen`:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  ...
  onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate({
      name: 'HomeScreen',
      params: { sort: 'Newest' },
      merge: true,
    });
  }}
>
  ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

More information: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen